# Find non trivial estimation for a Dirichlet series

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, inequality

I would like to estimate a Dirichlet series, for this I need a estimation for
$\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\left|e^{iu f(p^{k+1})}-e^{iu(1+f(p^{k}))}\right|$

where $f$ is real arithmetic addtive function with the property

$\left|f\left(p^k\right)\right| \leq k^{\alpha}, f(p)=1$
for prime numbers $p$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\alpha$ is independent of $k,p$. Furthermore let $u \in (-1,1)$. I can only obtain the trivial bound

$\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\left|e^{iu f(p^{k+1})}-e^{iu(1+f(p^{k}))}\right| \leq 2$
I would like to have something like 
$\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\left|e^{iu f(p^{k+1})}-e^{iu(1+f(p^{k}))}\right|=O(|u|)$
or weaker

$\left|e^{iu f(p^{k+1})}-e^{iu(1+f(p^{k}))}\right| \leq k |u| C$
where $C$ is  absolute constant.

I have tried this ansatz

\begin{align}\left|e^{iu f(p^k)}-e^{iu(1+f(p^{k-1})}\right|&=\left| \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(iuf(p^k))^j-(iu(1+f(p^{k-1}))^j}{j!} \right| \\
&=|u| \left|\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(u)^{j-1} \dfrac{(if(p^k))^j-(i(1+f(p^{k-1})))^j}{j!} \right| \\
 &\leq |u| k^{\alpha}  2\left|\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(u)^{j-1} 
\dfrac{(if(p^k))^{j-1}}{j!} \right|
\end{align}

but this seems not to be helpful... 
thanks for all ideas to handle this problem.

For $f(p^k)=k$ we have 
$\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\left|e^{iu f(p^{k+1})}-e^{iu(1+f(p^{k}))}\right|=0$.
And for $f(p^k)=1$ we have 
$$\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\left|e^{iu f(p^{k+1})}-e^{iu(1+f(p^{k}))}\right|\leq |u| (e-1),$$

but does it hold in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a estimation using the monotony of the integral operator, we have

\begin{align}&\left|e^{iu f(p^k)}-e^{iu(1+f(p^{k-1})}\right| \\
&=\left| 
if(p^k) \left( \dfrac{1}{if(p^k)} e^{iu f(p^k)}- \dfrac{1}{if(p^k)} \right)-i(f(p^{k-1})+1) \left( \dfrac{1}{i(f(p^{k-1})+1)} e^{iu f(p^k)}- \dfrac{1}{i(f(p^{k-1})+1)} \right)
 \right| \\
 \\&=\left| 
if(p^k) \int_0^u e^{i tf(p^k)} dt-i(f(p^{k-1})+1) \int_0^u e^{i t(1+f(p^{k-1})} dt
 \right| \\
&\leq  |u| (|f(p^k b)|+1+|f(p^{k-1}|) \\
& \leq |u| (k^{\alpha}+(k-1)^{\alpha}+1)
\end{align} 
with this estimation I can work bur still looking for better results.

Comment: if $\alpha > 1$ there is no better result than $2$. if $\alpha < 1$ there is no better result than this, and  don't see how this is not trivial. you should probably write the real problem you'd like to solve

Comment: Thanks for the  comment. Could you explain why?